# Why does it take two days for a question to become eligible for a bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I asked a question which I reasonably assume that someone here must have encountered (or encountered something very similar to it) before. I'm optimistic that if it got good attention, then I would receive an answer in a short time. That's because the answer to it should be a piece of cake to an expert in the field. However, the question did not get satisfactory attention and it doesn't seem to be getting anymore views than $26$ (perhaps there will be a small increase after I had posted this question).

Anyway, why do we have to wait two days in order to start a bounty? It is my own reputation that's decreasing, no one is getting hurt!

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20594/why-is-there-a-delay-for-setting-bounties

Answer (score 9):

One reason is that an active bounty prevents the question from being put on hold. This makes some sense if and *only if* the community had some *prior* chance to decide on the question's suitability.

Another reason is that having too many bounties decreases their efficiency. So, you putting a bounty on a question (where it might not be needed right away) has some negative effect for *others* having bountied questions.

Comment: But a bounty costs the user at least $50$ reputation. Users with high reputation do not usually ask many questions (if at all), users with low reputation (say $\le 100$) won't pay an such amount of their reputation, and new users can't even offer bounties.

Comment: I do not see how this invalidates the reasons. I would not want that somebody could even ask a single quite argumentative question without the community being able to intervene. (Especially not on a site like this were for better or worse moderator-intervention causes additional friction.)

Comment: To elaborate a little: The community can provide feedback through other means than closing a question - I certainly very often revise my questions based on community feedback (in comments) before placing a bounty on them. Given that bounty questions are more visible, it is desirable that they be well-reviewed by the community.